# facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect not working in Test environment but is in Development

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have redirect code which sends the user to our international page if a cookie is not set for languagePref.  It is set beforePageLoad on the XPage.  It works for firefox, Chrome, IE, and Safari in our DEV environment but in our TEST environment, it doesn't work for Safari.  Domino server is version 9.0.1FP9 in both environments. Code executed is as follows:

```
if (cookie.containsKey("languagePref")) {
        languageSel = cookie.get("languagePref").getValue();
        dBar.info("languageSel = " + languageSel);
    };
    //if no languagePref cookie has been set then send to International page
    if (languageSel == ""){
        println("No languagePref cookie - sending to intenational page");
        var intPage = configBean.getValue("HostURL") + "/international";
        return facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(intPage);
        //return facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("/international");      
    }
```

The cookie is set at our international page when one selects a Region.

We tried it on iPhone, iPad, and Mac, all with same result -- works in DEV but not in TEST.  Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Comment: Does the intPage variable contain the expected value for both dev and test?

Comment: There might be a problem with the current length of all cookies in the TEST environment. When there are many cookies, this limit could be reached and will cause that not all cookies are sent to server. Every browser has its own cookie size limit, I personally had this same situation a while ago :-(